# The domain of the function

Tags: gnuplot

Why is the domain of the function only for x >=0?

```
f(x) = 2*x**(5./3.) + 5 * x**(2./3.)
plot f(x)
```

[image]

**5/3 and 2/3**

[image]

Comment: is 5./3. same as 5/3 ?

Comment: Yes, but when I write 5/3, it is equal to 1 because of integer division

Comment: Did you try with 5/3 instead of (5./3.). It seems your division leads to floating number which restricting the domain to x >= 0

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/317546

Comment: Yes, I tried. The result it straight line (added to my qestion).

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
f(x) = 2*x**(5./3.) + 5 * x**(2./3.)
print f(-1)
```

You will see that the result is complex

```
{-1.5, 2.59807621135332}
```

So what you do expect?

Comment: I want to check how this function looks like. I determine the domain in math excercise. Thus, the domain is R but the gnuplot does not define negative numbers for the third root?

Comment: @Alex: The roots of negative numbers are complex. This is math and not a definition of gnuplot. Gnuplot handles it correctly. Try `plot real(f(x)), imag(f(x))`. If you stick to R (real number), your domain is x>=0 .

Comment: The third root of negative number is complex? $$\sqrt{3}{-216} = -6$$. Is that true?

Comment: @Alex: Indeed -6 is valid; as well as $3+i\sqrt{3}$ (`{3.0, 5.19615242270663}`) and $3-i\sqrt{3}$.